# Modifying Individual Pixels with SKShader

Tags: ios, swift

I am attempting to write a fragment shader for the app that I am working on. I pass my uniform into the shader which works but it works on the entire object. I want to be able to modify the object pixel by pixel. So my code now is....

```
let shader = SKShader( fileNamed: "Shader.fsh" );
shader.addUniform( SKUniform( name: "value", float: 1.0 ) );
m_image.shader = shader;
```

Here the uniform "value" will be the same for all pixels. But, for example, let's say I want to change "value" to "0.0" after a certain amount of pixels are drawn. So for example....

```
shader.addUniform( SKUniform( name: "value", float: 1.0 ) );
// 100 pixels are drawn
shader.addUniform( SKUniform( name: "value", float: 0.0 ) );
```

Is this even possible with SKShader? Would this have to be done in the shader source?

One idea I was thinking of was using an array uniform but it doesn't appear that SKShader allows this.

Thanks for any help is advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, the word *uniform* means unchanging — something that's the same in all cases or situations. Such is the way of shader uniforms: even though the shader code runs independently (and in parallel) for each pixel in a rendered, images, the value of a uniform variable input to the shader is the same across all pixels.

While you could, in theory, pass an array of values into the shader representing the colors for every pixel, that's essentially the same as passing an image (or just setting a texture image on the sprite)... at that point you're using a shader for nothing.

Instead, you typically want your GLSL(ish*) code to, if it's doing anything based on pixel location, find out the pixel coordinates it's writing to and calculate a result based on that. In a shader for `SKShader`, you get pixel coordinates from the `vec2 v_tex_coord` shader variable.

([This](http://battleofbrothers.com/sirryan/understanding-shaders-in-spritekit) looks like a decent tutorial (with links to others) for getting started on SpriteKit shaders. If you follow [other tutorials](http://www.raywenderlich.com/70208/opengl-es-pixel-shaders-tutorial) or [shader code libraries](https://www.shadertoy.com/) for help doing cool stuff with pixel shaders, you'll find ideas and algorithms you can reuse, but the ways they find the current output pixel will be different. In a shader for SpriteKit, you can usually safely replace `gl_FragCoord` with `v_tex_coord`.)

---

<sup>* `SKShader` doesn't use actual GLSL per se, It actually uses a subset of GLSL that automatically translates to appropriate GPU code for the device/renderer in use.</sup>

Comment: Okay, this is helpful. The problem I'm having now is that I have an arbitrary number of "values" which changes each time render is called. Is there a way to make an array uniform with SKShader?

Comment: No, see SKUniformType for the types of uniform available with SKShader.

Comment: See also SKAttribute, introduced in iOS 10 / macOS 10.12 / etc (after the original Q&A here). That controls another way to get data to a shader, which can vary in different ways.